# Delete multiple item from array - Redux State

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm working on react app with redux. I want to delete multiple item from array. I write below code in my reducer which delete single item from array but i want to delete multiple item.

```
case DELETE_LINK:  
    let dltLink = state.filter(item => {
            return item._id !== action.data._id

    }) 
    return {
        ...state,
        parentFolderlinks: dltLink
    };
```

Comment: ID's tend to indicate uniqueness (*or they should!*), so using any specific id likely won't allow you to remove multiple elements from an array.  Can you provide more detail as to what needs to be deleted from a links array?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to filter links from `state.parentFolderlinks`, say you have the ids in `action.data.ids`, you could

```js
case DELETE_LINK:
    const parentFolderlinks = state.parentFolderlinks.filter(item => {
            return !action.data.ids.includes(item._id);
    });
    return {
        ...state,
        parentFolderlinks
    };
```

Comment: `return !action.data.ids.includes(item.id)` would be more effective as it doesn't have to go through the whole `action.data.ids` array.

Answer (score 1):

On what basis would you like to filter items? I assume that multiple items will not have the same `id`.

Below example shows how we can filter multiple items in redux. In this case, foods state with items that has `type` as `fruit` and removes everything else.

```js
// initial state with all types of foods
const initialState = {
    "foods": [
        {
            name: "apple", 
            type: "fruit"
        }, 
        {
            name: "orange", 
            type: "fruit"
        }, 
        {
            name: "broccoli", 
            type: "vegetable"
        }, 
        {
            name: "spinach", 
            type: "vegetable"
        }, 
    ]
}

// sample reducer that shows how to delete multiple items 
export default (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
    
    // delete multiple items that does not have type fruit
    // i.e both brocolli and spinach are removed because they have type vegetable
    case DELETE_ITEMS_WITHOUT_TYPE_FRUIT:
        const onlyFruits = state.foods.filter(food => food.type === "fruit");

        return {
            ...state, 
            foods: onlyFruits
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could map over the state and run it through a function that works out if you want to keep it or not (I don't know what your logic is for that) then return the array at the end

```
const keepThisItem =(item) => {
   return item.keep
}

case DELETE_LINK:
    let itemsToKeep = []  
    let dltLink = state.map(item => {
        if(keepThisItem(item){
            itemsToKeep.push(item)
        }
        return itemsToKeep
    })
```

Comment: For iteratring over an array the `forEach` method I (without a return) is what you want. Using `map` here would return an array of arrays to keep. Not sure this answers the op question, either